# How can I read n days before every timestep of every year?

Tags: r

I have this dataframe which covers data from 1960-1980.

```
dput->structure(list(DATE = 19620101:19620106, PRECIP = c(10.54, 6.39, 
0.01, 0, 0.02, 20.94), OBS_Q = c(2.39, 2.38, 2.22, 2.24, 2.26, 
5.13)), .Names = c("DATE", "PRECIP", "OBS_Q"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

All I want to do is:

- Mention a particular date (Either as 19620110 or 10)
- Read n days of data before this particular date from EVERY year of this dataset.

Expected output (say n=2,date=19620103)

```
19620101    10.54   2.39
19620102    6.39    2.38
19630101    11.54   3.39
19630102    62.39   3.38
19640101    12.54   4.39
19640102    6.39    5.38
*
*
19800101    12.12   3.44
19800102    12.33   3.45
```

I am not sure how to proceed on this. Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: In the output you mention, you read n days of data - each year - AFTER this particular date. So you want AFTER or BEFORE ?

Comment: Sorry, I want all. It's the date matters (0103), not the year. So if I mention 19650103, I want 3 years  before it as well. Thanks

Comment: However, it will be nice to have an option, where I can only use the data before a particular year. So, If I mention a date in 1970, I use only the years before it. But I can figure it out later I guess.

Answer (score 1):

So here is a non-elegant way to do it. The idea is to check only for the months and days (and ignore the year of the input). It'd be pretty easy to incorporate any condition on the years if necessary. So first:

```
library(dplyr) # data manipulation
library(lubridate) # time and dates manipulation

df <- data.frame(DATE = c(19620101:19620106,19630101:19630106), 
                 PRECIP = c(10.54, 6.39, 0.01, 0, 0.02, 20.94,10.54, 6.39, 0.01, 0, 0.02, 20.94), 
                 OBS_Q = c(2.39, 2.38, 2.22, 2.24, 2.26, 5.13,2.39, 2.38, 2.22, 2.24, 2.26, 5.13))

# Here you actually specify what days to select. Only the "0106" part matters here
day_in_a_year <- paste0("1962", "0106")
days_shown <- 2 # how many days per year to show
# so, in this case, select 6th January and the day before

df %>% mutate(DATE = ymd(DATE)) %>% 
  arrange(DATE) %>%
  filter(between(day(DATE),   day(ymd(day_in_a_year) - days(days_shown - 1)),   day(ymd(day_in_a_year))),
         between(month(DATE), month(ymd(day_in_a_year) - days(days_shown - 1)), month(ymd(day_in_a_year))))

#         DATE PRECIP OBS_Q
# 1 1962-01-05   0.02  2.26
# 2 1962-01-06  20.94  5.13
# 3 1963-01-05   0.02  2.26
# 4 1963-01-06  20.94  5.13
```

Edit:

Since you'd like to select years before (including) the year of input date, you could use something like this:

```
 df %>% mutate(DATE = ymd(DATE)) %>% 
   arrange(DATE) %>%
   filter(between(day(DATE),  day(ymd(day_in_a_year) - days(days_shown - 1)),  day(ymd(day_in_a_year))),
          between(month(DATE), month(ymd(day_in_a_year) - days(days_shown - 1)), month(ymd(day_in_a_year))),
          year(DATE) <= year(ymd(day_in_a_year)))
```